# Can't seem to get form to appear inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a form that sticks at the bottom of the div that says "General" and "programming."

**Here's a picture:**
[image: Heres a picture]

I've tried many things, and can't seem to get the form to appear... When I do get *something* to appear, I can't make it stick to the bottom either. Can anyone help?

I'm using bootstrap

Heres my HTML:

```
<div class="chatroom">
  <div id="contain">
    <div id="channels">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">General</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Programming</a>
      </div>
       <div id="bar"></div>
       <form id="create-channel">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="c" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="chat">
      <ul id="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      <div class="input">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="m" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: azure;
  background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
}

.chatroom {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;

  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity:.8;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
.input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 98%;
  margin-left:1%;
  margin-top: auto;
}

#chat .form-control{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

#chat{
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  float: right;
  height:100%;
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#channels{
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  width:25%;
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#bar{
  background-color:black;
  height:100%;
  float: right;
  width: 3px;
}
#contain{
  height:100%;
}
.list-group{
  font-family: "Avant Garde",Avantgarde,"Century Gothic",CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  width:calc(100% - 3px);
  background-color:#bcbcbc;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It's right there in your screenshot, stuck to the bottom. All you have is a single input, are you expecting more?

Comment: I'm trying to get a second form to appear in the div on the left, where it says "General" and "programming"

Comment: Got it! I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you remove the div with id `#bar`? It seems that by floating that to the right, you get some layout funk.

By removing that, the form field shows up then you can style it as you desire:

http://jsfiddle.net/20nhLz3x/4/

Comment: The bar is definitely causing funk. But I'd like to keep it there, as it acts as a stylistic divider. Is there any way to include it?

Comment: @dane2476 sure, i see what you're going for. what i'd recommend is removing the bar then using `border-right` to apply the styling you're looking for. you may need to adjust a few other layout properties as well. see my updated link

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when I rearrange the bar div below your form. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/vj2fyuLm/

```
  <form id="create-channel">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="c" class="form-control" placeholder="one" autocomplete="off"></div>
  </form>
  <div id="bar"></div>
```

**Update**

You can have your entire form inside the list group like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vj2fyuLm/3/

```
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">General</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Programming</a>

         <form id="create-channel">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="c" class="form-control" placeholder="one" autocomplete="off"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: This cuts off the bar which should fully extend to the top of the entire container.. for a reason I don't understand lol

Comment: are you using the bar for something else in js? else you can use css and do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/vj2fyuLm/2/